# Symfony2 + Doctrine selective relationships forms

Tags: mysql, symfony, collections, doctrine, relationship

I have two tables, `Clientes` and `Servicios` they have relationships, I want doctrine return the client with it's services only instead of all services that exists when I'm using the addAction form, for example:

```
`Client: Foo

     Services:
         Bar
         Bar2
         Bar3
Client: Foo2

     Services:
         Bar2
         Bar7
Client: Foo3

     Services:
         Bar`
```

I don't know how to tell Symfony2 or Doctrine that `client Foo` has X services assigned...

This is doctrine yml

```
Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Clientes:
    type: entity
    table: clientes
    id:
        id:
          type: integer
          unsigned: false
          nullable: false
          generator:
              strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        nombre:
            type: string
            length: 250
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
    manyToOne:
        servicio:
            targetEntity: Servicios
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: cliente
            joinColumns:
                servicio_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    oneToMany:
        incidencia:
            targetEntity: Incidencias
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: cliente
            inversedBy: null
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
Pge\IncidenciasBundle\Entity\Servicios:
    type: entity
    table: servicios
    id:
        id:
          type: integer
          unsigned: false
          nullable: false
          generator:
              strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        nombre:
            type: string
            length: 250
            fixed: false
            nullable: true
    oneToMany:
        cliente:
            targetEntity: Clientes
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: servicio
            inversedBy: null
            orphanRemoval: false
        incidencia:
            targetEntity: Incidencias
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: servicio
            inversedBy: null
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Comment: Don;t take this the wrong way but it's generally considered a bad idea to 1 - post a question, 2 - receive a valid answer to the question, 3 - change the question to something completely different.  It becomes very confusing for someone to read the question, see what looks like a valid yaml and then see an answer saying the yaml is wrong.  I suppose I could delete my answer but that's not really my job.

Answer (score 1):

Doctrine cannot determine which column is supposed to be your primary key.

Move your id to up one level in your yaml files:

```
table: servicios

id:
    id:
        type: integer
        unsigned: false
        nullable: false
        generator:
            strategy: IDENTITY
fields:
```

Then run app/console doctrine:schema:create --dump-sql

And see what you get.  There may be other errors.  I didn't look real close.  If necessary, start with a stripped down yaml file then add one field at a time.  I suspect you want unsigned to be true as well.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. But the problem is that I want doctrine return the `client` with it's services **only** instead of **all** services that exists when I'm using the `addAction` form, I don't know if I'm explaining good...

Comment: No idea what you are saying.  The question does not say anything about form actions.  I though this was a "how to define relations" type question.  Hopefully someone else can help.